# Loop - Extract text for record until the next record

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

My dummy file looks like this:

```
  >Tom
  text
  text text, year = 16 
  text 
  text
  text
  Grades . . . . 10
  Grades . . . . 9
  >Ann  
  text
  text text, year = 17 
  text 
  Grades . . . . 10
  Grades . . . . 10
  Grades . . . . 9
```

I want to:
For every name assign value, extract year & last number in Grades lines.
For the output like this:

```
  1 Tom 
  1 year = 16
  1 10
  1 9 
  2 Ann
  2 year = 17
  2 10
  2 10
  2 9
```

I don't know how could I modify text from record until next record. It could be possible to `grep '^>' -An` , but line number differs for every record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the leading whitespace is absent from your real files, here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'sub(/^>/,"") { print ++i, $0 } /Grades/ { print i, $NF } /year =/ { print i, "year = ", $NF }' file
```

Results:

```
1 Tom
1 year =  16
1 10
1 9
2 Ann  
2 year =  17
2 10
2 10
2 9
```

Comment: Sure. `/Grades/ { print i, $NF }` means: on each line containing 'Grades', print the value of `i`, followed by the last field in that line. `NF` is short for number of fields, `$NF` is the last field. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I got it. And is there equivalent to the first field (as `$NF` to the last field) (besides $1)?

Comment: Cool. `$1` is the first field. Why would you ever need anything else? If you need two copies, just use a variable: `{ x = $1 }`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN{ $/ = ">"; $i=0} chomp; next unless length; $i++; say "$i $_" for /(.+)/, /(year\s*=.+)/, /grades.+?(\d+)/gi' file
```